# Reading JSON (with jQuery) produced by PHP containing @attributes

Tags: php, jquery, attributes, json

What are those `@attributes` thing I have in my JSON file and how can I read that with JQuery?

The JSON "text" I use is produced with `json_encode` in PHP from an array of custom objects.

Here's a reduced JSON file:

```
{ "movies" : [ { "url":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Nsd7ZcXnL6k", title":{"@attributes":{"type":"text"},"0":"**Title here**"} ] }
```

I can read the URL easily with the following code :

```
 $.getJSON(url, function(json){
    $.each(json.movies,function(i,item) {
        alert(item.url);  
    });
 });
```

How can I read the title `Title here` value ?

**UPDATE**

Well, I still don't know what the `@attributes` are, but I know why they were in my final JSON file. I was using `$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);` to read a XML and then `$sxml->title` to read a title, wich is not a string apparently but some kind of PHP object.

Instead of

```
$this->title = $sxml->title
```

I used

```
$this->title = $sxml->title . ""
```

(Ot's converting the object into a string value). Maybe there's a more intelligent way of doing this?

If you have a recent PHP, it supports casting, so you can use

```
(string)$xml->title
```

and it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json){

    $.each(json.movies,function(i,item) {
        alert(item.url); 
        alert(item.title[0]); 
    });
 });
```

Comment: Ah, that's what that 0 is for! Thanks! ;)